# How to create those app images for app in google play store

Tags: android

am about to publish my a droid application, but the problem is that, I don't know how to create images/photo shot of my app being used. I see other apps with images of other app being used. Can someone explain how to do this to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use screen capture in Android Studio and any online services for resize

Answer (score 0):

Most Android phones also let users take screenshots by pressing Power and Volume down button at the same time. This is generally what I've used to take screenshots for Google Play.